# Codeigniter - Login Page With Multi Language Option

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wana make a newsletter system for users to send information to us but here we need a two languages form so we make a two languages form arabic and english but when i use to call with controller only the english version coming , when i click on arabic so url not found for this i dont know what to do because i am new in php codeigniter.

for guidence and suggestions i also mention the file names with view and controller because when i sort this error then i start working on form and submission of data in db but first i need to figure out this, we have already make this form in simple php but now we need to move on to codeigniter, i hope to see a good suggestions then i can solve this problem.

view 
 - ar_login.php
 - en_login.php

controler
 - welcome.php

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: use CI language class for this. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/language.html

Answer (score 0):

Well.. in your controller, put

```
function login($language){

  // your data variables...
  if($language == 'ar'){
    $this->load->view('ar_login',$data);
  } elsif($language == 'en') {
    $this->load->view('en_login',$data);
  } else {
    show_404();
  }
}
```

in config/routes.php add

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = "your_controller/login/$1";
```

hope that helps

so if you access http://yoursite.com/login/ar  this will route you to arabic
if you access yoursite.com/login/en will display english
else will put a 404 message.